Buffer array в opus файл node js
Из этого
[
  <Buffer 78 00 40 ad e1 54 ea 4a e3 06 f9 48 e1 f0 03 a9 4a f6 72 ef b0 0b 58 9b 11 a4 88 26 ce f2 7c c3 e7 de b7 38 25 af ff 22 e8 b0 6b 77 b9 0f a1 ea bd 59 ... 28 more bytes>,
  <Buffer 78 08 9c 98 b3 c2 9d dc 11 dc 7f 2f ef 86 98 ee 3e e9 88 f1 4d 31 86 c7 0f ab 84 9e 9b 79 ad 5b 5b 7b 43 20 78 5d a9 d1 96 3d c4 56 27 cb 70 ca cb 17 ... 23 more bytes>,
  <Buffer 78 08 1b 26 78 89 0d 52 3f b8 33 f2 35 5f f2 9e 58 db 9e 53 2d 1a 7a bc ef 83 d3 ad 17 89 3f c0 d4 7a da a1 67 b2 b8 58 94 d3 a2 e1 f8 9f 0a 33 08 03 ... 43 more bytes>,
]

Сделать opus файл.
(пусть надписи more bytes вас не смущают, это особенность терминала)
Я пробовал делать что-то типа такого:
buffer.toString("utf8")

не opus файл из этого не получается

А зачем вы пытаетесь преобразовать его в utf8? Попробуйте 'binary'.

Не помогло. Сейчас пробую с локальными файлами на компьютере. И делаю Buffer.from из точно рабочего файла. А потом снова в файл с помощью toString и это не работает. Все типы попробовал (utf8, base64, binary и т. д.). Кодировку одну и ту же ставлю

А зачем вы вообще хотите сделать строку из бинарных данных???

Возможно это я что-то не понимаю, но мне нужно бинарные данные преобразовать в файл, который я смогу послушать. А вообще я их получаю их от discord api. Просто щас еще пробую на локальных файлах

Buffer можно просто записать в файл без всякого преобразования.
